# How to get dropwizard to accept all security roles when invoking a protected resource

Tags: security, authentication, dropwizard

I'm running the dropwizard example from:
https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/tree/master/dropwizard-example

which includes an example how to protect a resource using http basic authentication.
In the example the user must belong to a specific role to access the resource:

```
@Path("/protected")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class ProtectedResource {
    @RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
    @GET
    public String showSecret(@Auth User user) {
        return String.format("Hey there, %s. You know the secret! %d", user.getName(), user.getId());
    }
}
```

I have a scenario where I want to enforce authentication, through the filter, but once authenticated I want all users to access the resource.
So my question is: how to indicate that all roles should be allowed to access  the resource? I've tried replacing @RolesAllowed with @PermitAll but I'm getting:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot inject Custom principal into unauthenticated request
! at io.dropwizard.auth.AuthValueFactoryProvider$AuthValueFactory.provide(AuthValueFactoryProvider.java:77) ~[dropwizard-auth-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.9.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Answer (score 1):

This was not supported in the first implementation of io.dropwizard.auth.AuthDynamicFeature. @PermitAll support has been introduced in v0.9.0-rc3.